useAsyncData status returning idle
const { data, status, error, refresh, clear } = await useAsyncData(
  'campaign',
   () => $fetch(`${$request.baseUrl}/cs/v1/campaign/find/${route.params.campaign}?mode=${route.query.mode || ''}`, {method: 'POST'}),
   {
    server: true, 
    deep: false
   }
)
console.log(data.value, status.value)

I have a NUXT 3 app and I am trying to implement SSR. There's a page where I have to render campaigns and I would like to pass set SEO info. However, this doesn't seem to be working properly because then I log data.value and status.value, status shows idle and data show null. I have checked with the NUXT docs and no luck. Please what I'm I doing wrong

If you want to console.log when a reactive variable changes, you can watch it:
const { data, status, error, refresh, clear } = await useAsyncData(
  'campaign',
   () => $fetch(`${$request.baseUrl}/cs/v1/campaign/find/${route.params.campaign}?mode=${route.query.mode || ''}`, {method: 'POST'}),
   {
    server: true, 
    deep: false
   }
)
watchEffect(() => {
   console.log(data.value, status.value)
}

If you're looking to set seo tags based on the returned value, have a look at useSeoMeta.
In your case it might look something like this
const { data, status, error, refresh, clear } = await useAsyncData(
  'campaign',
   () => $fetch(`${$request.baseUrl}/cs/v1/campaign/find/${route.params.campaign}?mode=${route.query.mode || ''}`, {method: 'POST'}),
   {
    server: true, 
    deep: false
   }
)
useSeoMeta({title: () => data.value.title})

PS. If you're not doing anything other than data fetching in useAsyncData, you can use useFetch.
